# How to determine what IP addresses are available in a hosts table?

Tags: bash, shell, networking, awk, sed

I'm working on a script that will read from the /etc/hosts file and determine what IPs are available in the hosts file.

The way the hosts file will look is as followed:

```
172.17.164.2 System1
172.17.164.3 System2
172.17.164.4 System3
172.17.164.5 System4
172.17.164.6 System5
172.17.164.7
172.17.164.8
172.17.164.9
172.17.164.10
```

My question is, how do I read each line and check to see if the second field is missing? If the hosts file is missing the hostname, then that means the IP is available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` (as suggested by the tag), checking if the number of fields on a given record is one.  To get a list of "free" addresses:

```
awk '(NF == 1) { print; }' </etc/hosts
```

That may be too simple, if your `/etc/hosts` file contains comments.  You can filter those out by skipping comment-lines:

```
awk '/^#/ { next; } (NF == 1) { print; }' </etc/hosts
```

`awk` scripts are pattern (or condition) and action pairs:

- In the first script, `awk` checks `NF` — the number of *fields* on the line (which by default are blank-separated), and prints each line with a single field.
- The second script addresses the problem of a `/etc/hosts` file with comments by checking for lines beginning with "#", and skipping further processing of those lines (by skipping to the `next` line).

Comment: Can you explain the syntax to awk? I don't understand how you came up with that.

Answer (score 0):

For the data given, you could use `grep -v System /etc/hosts`.

For a more general solution, use `egrep -v "\S+\s+\S+" /etc/hosts`, which means show me any lines that do not contain something that is not whitespace followed by whitespace followed by something that is not whitespace, e.g. at least two words.

Comment: very specific to the example data, but isn't general-purpose enough for the stated question of "...if the second field is *missing*"

Comment: @JeffSchaller True enough, but easy to generalize.